# Adding picture and comment to cell causes issue

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, closedxml

I am using the following code to add a comment :

```
ws.Cell("A5").Comment.SetVisible().AddText("sample");
ws.PageSetup.SetShowComments(XLShowCommentsValues.AsDisplayed);
```

When I comment out the following code, which adds an image to the excel document, then the comment works. But with this code uncommented, the below error occurs:

```
XLPicture pic = new XLPicture
{
    NoChangeAspect = true,
    NoMove = true,
    NoResize = true,
    ImageStream = memo,
    Name = "Export Image",
    PaddingX = 12,
    PaddingY = 18
};

XLMarker fMark = new XLMarker { ColumnId = 1, RowId = 1 };
pic.AddMarker(fMark);
workSheet.AddPicture(pic);
```

Error is :
[image]

Comment: Does adding a picture without a comment work? Does it only fail when you add both a picture and a comment to the document?

Comment: yes it does !!! and if I only comment .addpicture() method then  comment works, not able to figure out the issue !

Comment: Afraid not, it sounds like a possible bug with ClosedXML. You might need to contact the developer or find an alternative way around the issue. Maybe use ClosedXML for the comment, but OpenXML for adding the picture? A pain, but sadly if you can't get support from the ClosedXML developer, it might be the only way